# Pandas + PyQT5 открытие датафрейма после прохождения по нему .str.contains

Tags: python, pyqt5, pandas

Есть необходимость подгружать файл в *Excel*, далее искать по нему определенные строки с помощью *.str.contains* и выводить это в виде таблице с помощью *PyQt5*. В конечном итоге мне надо выводить из нового датафрейма только два столбца, а не все.
Ранее уже подсказали как это сделать просто с файлом Excel, без поиска. Я попытался модифицировать код под свою задачу, но так не работает.

Оригинальная таблица состоит из 46 столбцов, с большим количеством пустых ячеек, а где есть содержимое ,оно состоит так же в основном из текста.

Суть в том, что бы загрузить этот файл, пройти по строкам `.str.contain` в столбце *Последний комментарий* , там отобрать нужные строки, и вывести на экран таблице из двух столбцов *Номер* и *Последний комментарий* которые у нас были отобраны по ранее заданным критериям.

Пример таблицы на выходе с найденным нужными строками

| Номер | Последний комментарий |
| --- | --- |
| ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |

Пример вывода `print(f'{df2}')`

|  | Номер | Последний комментарий |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 8 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 9 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 11 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 13 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 16 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 19 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 21 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 46 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |
| 47 | ARC-31717xxxx | много букв и в этом столбце надо искать |

загрузка файла проходит, но програма закрывается с ошибками.

> ```
>  SettingWithCopyWarning: 
>  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>   df2.fillna('', inplace=True) Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
> ```

Мой код

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 49, 800, 521))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузка"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                   # <----
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.upload_xlsx)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def upload_xlsx(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open Excel File ',
            "",
            "Excel File (*.xlsx)"
        )
        # -        fname = fnameTuple[0]

        if fname:
            df = pd.read_excel(fname)
            tags = [r'\bн/о', r'\bакту', r'\bно3', r'\bМОУ']
            df2 = df[df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains('|'.join(tags))]
            self.loadExcelData(df2)

    def loadExcelData(self, df2):
        df2.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df2.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df2.shape[1])
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df2.columns)

        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код до модификации

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd  # <----


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.UpLoad_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setFont(font)
        self.UpLoad_btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.UpLoad_btn.setObjectName("UpLoad_btn")

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()  

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.UpLoad_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузка"))





class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)  # <----

        self.UpLoad_btn.clicked.connect(self.upload_xlsx)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.UpLoad_btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    def upload_xlsx(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open Excel File ',
            "",
            "Excel File (*.xlsx)"
        )

        if fname:
            df = pd.read_excel(fname)
            self.loadExcelData(df)

    def loadExcelData(self, df):
        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()  # <----
    w.show()  # <----
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `Ответственный работник          Номер  ...  Завершена Новостройка
0                       NaN  CRM-317170613  ...        NaN         NaN
8                       NaN  CRM-317114161  ...        NaN         NaN
9                       NaN  CRM-317107710  ...        NaN         NaN
11                      NaN  CRM-317173519  ...        NaN         NaN
13                      NaN  CRM-317172056  ...        NaN         NaN
16                      NaN  CRM-317143791  ...        NaN         NaN
19                      NaN  CRM-317172372  ...        NaN         NaN`

Comment: `119                     NaN  CRM-317098410  ...        NaN         NaN
 132                     NaN  CRM-317073553  ...        NaN         NaN
 140                     NaN  CRM-317035238  ...        NaN         NaN

[15 rows x 46 columns]

Process finished with exit code `

Comment: Результат команды `print(f'{df2}')` , к сожалению не получается вывести ровнее. Там большая таблица строчных данных, много пустых столбцов, но меня из всего этого интересуют два. Один с большими текстовыми комментариями, в которых надо искать ключевые слова и выводить из столбца с номером заявки - собственно этот номер где было найдено.

Comment: Добавил информацию. Надеюсь исчерпывающею.

Comment: @S. Nick Спасибо! Поправил. Он стал выводить из в визуальный интерфейс, но с пустыми строками и только до 15 строки, те  далеко не все.  `df2.dropna(how='all')` применение не дает результат. С чем может быть связано такой результат? Или выделить это отдельным вопросом?

Comment: Мысли вслух:
- метод `def loadExcelData(self, df):` работает если `df` правильный;
- значит с `df2` что-то не то;
- `df2` в вашем случае формируется строкой 
`df2 = df[df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains('|'.join(tags))]`, 
значит проблема в этой строке;
- и это проблема не связана с PyQt и скать ее надо в pandas;
- у меня нет  опыта работы с pandas, но скажу что строка 
`df2 = df[df['Последний комментарий'].str.contains('кт', case=False, na=False, regex=False)]` 
работает для меня с моими исходными данными и 
в итоге я вывожу один столбец со строками, в которых обнаружено 'кт'

Comment: - если вы разместите исходные данные и все необходимое для тестирования, 
например на github, я по возможности попробую протестировать их;
- если задавать новый вопрос, то метки должны быть `python` и `pandas`, 
и вопрос дожен касаться того, как с одних исходных данных (`df = ...`) 
получить друние данные (`df2 = ...`) используя (`... .str.contains(...)`)